# Filtering nested properties in subgraph (the graph)

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, thegraph

Is it possible to filter subgraph using "where" when properties are nested?

For example if we have query like this one, can we filter it by application name?

```
{
  challenges(where: {something?}) {
    challenger
    outcome
    application {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried it like this one but it doesn't work

```
{
  challenges(where: {application: {name: "something"}) {
    challenger
    outcome
    application {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, The Graph [does not currently support nested queries](https://github.com/graphprotocol/graph-node/issues/2539#issuecomment-855979841). They currently have it on the roadmap, so my recommendation is to subscribe to their releases in their [repository](https://github.com/graphprotocol/graph-node) or check their #announcements channel in [Discord](https://discord.gg/vtvv7FP).

Comment: This answer is no longer up-to-date as of June 28, 2022. [This PR](https://github.com/graphprotocol/graph-node/pull/3184#issuecomment-1167237424) added support for nested queries.

Answer (score 5):

You can write:

```
{
  challenges(where: {application_: {name: "something"}) {
    challenger
    outcome
    application {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

> Notice `_` after the property name

**Docs:**
https://thegraph.com/docs/en/querying/graphql-api/#example-for-nested-entity-filtering